# Query result is empty if table expression query is empty

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to run a query something like this

```
SELECT kk.first_col, ll.second_col
  FROM (SELECT 2 first_col FROM dual) kk,
       (SELECT 1 second_col FROM dual WHERE 1 = 2) ll
```

Where one of the table expressions may return values or not.
In this example `kk` returns row but `ll` don't (for obvious reason).
And as a result if I run whole query I get 0 rows returned.
My expectations is to get result like this:

```
|FIRST_COL|SECOND_COL|
|2        |          |
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I removed the mysql tag, because the syntax looks like Oracle.

Comment: You have used 1 = 2 condition which is always false. That means "ll" does not contain any record and joining it with "kk" will result in 0 records fetched.

Comment: Your subqueries in the `FROM` clause are generating two derived tables, the first with one row, the second with zero. Putting N tables in `FROM` clause separated by `,` has the same effect as a `CROSS JOIN`, which is an `INNER JOIN` with `ON 1=1`... as it will cross all rows, one x zero = zero rows...

Comment: You need to separate tables by comma in Oracle

Comment: your question is incomplete. one cannot understand, what you want to get, if both queries return the same value. to you want to get one row for that (left/inner/full join) or product of all (cross join). Also, what did you try?

Comment: If second queries does not return anything I get empty result set of my whole query. I want that my first column would be filled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is almost okay, you just need to return the data from first table even when no data were found on second table.

In SQL, this job is done with `LEFT JOIN`. Try this:

```
SELECT 
  kk.first_col, 
  ll.second_col
FROM (SELECT 2 first_col FROM dual) kk
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 second_col FROM dual WHERE 1 = 2) ll ON 1=1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use commas in the `from` clause.

For this particular query, you seem to want one row with two columns.  Just use two scalar subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT 2 first_col FROM dual) as first_col,
       (SELECT 1 second_col FROM dual WHERE 1 = 2) second_col
FROM dual;
```

Comment: I need commas in from clause in oracle

Answer (score 1):

You must join the 2 tables:

```
SELECT kk.first_col, ll.second_col
  FROM (SELECT 2 first_col FROM dual) kk
  FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT 1 second_col FROM dual WHERE 1 = 2) ll ON kk.firstcol = ll.secondcol
```

Oracle recommends not to use the oracle-join-syntax according to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm

Please note, that full outer joins are slow on big tables with oracle up to 10g, they are faster since 11g

Comment: I get ORA-01468 if I try to run your query

Comment: ORA-00920 I get now

Comment: @swe: please remove "," after alias "kk". Also column names in the joining condition are wrong. The main thing as you are using ANSI join there's no need to use (+) in the joining condition.

Comment: @hemalp108 Thx, that is the problem if you copy&paste... edited as suggested.